# how to change Image button on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover

I want to change the image button from green to yellow on rollover.

Here is my CSS code

```
 a#try-it-button {
    width:273px;
    height:47px;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:372px;
    background:url(../image/try-it-green.png);

}
a#try-it-button:hover {
        width:273px;
    height:47px;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:372px;
    background:url(../image/try-it-orange.png);
}
a.alt { display: none; }
```

My html code

```
<div id="y-moringa">


<a id="try-it-button" href="#"><span class="alt"></span></a>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way does it not work? If the link (`a`) has visible content, then this should [work already](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hR589/) using just CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Add `float: left` or `display: inline-block` or `display: block` to `a#try-it-button`.

Which one of those you want really depends on the layout you desire.

You don't need to duplicate all the properties on `:hover` (except for the new `background`).

What you should actually be doing here is using ["CSS Sprites"](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/) (there are many benefits), and adjusting the `background-position` on `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but give this a shot:

```
a#try-it-button {
    width:273px;
    height:47px;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:372px;
    display:block; // <-- **I added this**
    background:url(../image/try-it-green.png);

}
a#try-it-button:hover {
    background:url(../image/try-it-orange.png);
}
```